How can I write text to a specific portion in a file?
I have a file that currently contains sample times that being continuously written to the file:
[SampleTimes]
0=0
853=0.021325
1706=0.04265

I want to add a commment section so that the file will look like this:
[SampleTimes]
0=0
853=0.021325
1706=0.04265

[Comments]
3.69555,0,0,65536,test text
7.25082,0,0,65536,asdffdsa
9.74452,0,0,65536,qwert

However, the comment section are events that are also being continuously written to file. Is there a way to shift the cursor to append to the sample times when needed and then shift it back to append to the end of the file when a comment comes in?
This file is being read while we are writing to it  in real time by another software that requires the file to be in this specific format.
I've seen other posts but they all recreate the file which I can't do as there could be some data loss.

which I can't do as there could be some data loss One way to be safe is to write a new file to a temporary filename. When that write succeeds delete the original file and rename the temporary to the original name. This is how some commercial software works.

why not simply write SampleTimes to one file and Comments to a second one?

The file has to be in that format as the software we are using requires files to be in this specific format.

is this a single threaded program?  Multi threaded?  Multiprocess?

Single threaded

"The file has to be in that format" thats ok, once in a while you can merge the two files into one.

please try to be more specific. "I can't do as there could be some data loss" what do you mean exactly? What is that other software? Is it also reading continuously? at the same time your are writing continuously?

The other software is continuously reading as we are writing

You can't insert new text into the middle of a file if you are expecting it to preserve and shift down the remaining text. The only way to handle this is to create a whole new file - copy the preceding text from the old file, then write the new text, then copy the remaining text from the old file - and then close and replace the old file with the new file.

Simply stated, you're asking for the impossible.

To overwrite data in a file, position using seekp, then start writing.  Inserting into the middle of file is a lot of work; most tasks write to a new file instead.

@BenMoo keep a database and provide an EXPORT function that can write the files according to the output spec. Probably a lot better for your performance too

If the file is small, upload the file contents to the unordered_map<string, vector<string>>, overwrite the file with each update.

Overwriting to a file is best performed when the records are fixed length.  In this case, you might as well use a database.

It sounds like you seem to think that it is a trivial operation to insert into the middle of the file. Even if you seek to a point in the middle of the file to start writing, you will first need to move the existing contents later in the file, leaving the file in a potentially corrupt state whilst this movement is occurring. What mechanism is there currently to ensure the second program does not read a partially written file?  Assuming there is no mechanism, then as others have already said, you should probably look at a more robust solution, e.g. database.

Files are really, really dumb. Making them do smart things like handle data inserted into the middle is a LOT of work.
